# Action Script 3 , SharedObject , Save Loader Data

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, shared-objects

I have a question 
where is my mistake and how can I improve it?
the main thing is Image data have saved but I can't load it again

my data is an image

I get this error every time I have tried to load the loader

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object@2802e5c9 to flash.display.Loader.
at LoadAndSaveImage_fla::MainTimeline/LOADING_IMAGE()
```

Here is my code :

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var MY_DATA:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("Kianoosh");

BROWSE.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, BROWSE_CLICKED);
SAVE.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, SAVE_CLICKED);
FR.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, SELECTED);
FR.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, COMPLETED);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LOAD_COMPLETE);
LOADING_BTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, LOADING_IMAGE);

function BROWSE_CLICKED(evt:MouseEvent)
{
    FR.browse();
}
function SELECTED(Event)
{
    FR.load();
}
function COMPLETED(evt:Event)
{
    loader.loadBytes(evt.currentTarget.data);
}
function SAVE_CLICKED(MouseEvent)
{
    MY_DATA.data.MY_IMAGE = loader;
    MY_DATA.flush();
}
function LOADING_IMAGE(MouseEvent)
{
    loader = MY_DATA.data.MY_IMAGE;
} 

UIL.addChild(loader);

function LOAD_COMPLETE(Event)
{
    loader.width = UIL.width;
    loader.height = UIL.height;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't save any UI object into SharedObject, but you can save loaded bytes.
When you need to recover image, just load bytes and instantiate a new Image.